# Link in template for routers of rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I set rest_framework and have the page named `api`

```
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'genres', GenreViewSet)
router.register(r'blogs',BlogViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/',include(router.urls), name='api') #name is here???
]
```

but in template , I can not access the page

```
<a href="{% url 'api' %}">api</a>
```

It shows the error , I think I am basically somehow wrong though...

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'api' not found. 'api' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `name` attribute on "included" paths.
But you can set the `namespace` attribute to access the included views with:
`{% url 'namespace:url_name' %}`